# Convert Xml request to Object Spring Boot

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Created a spring boot rest service which accepts XML as a request and converts it into object and then inserts it into database.
I used Jackson dataformat dependency for directly converting the xml request to object but getting an error .

The controller class is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getRequestData",method=RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> putDataIntoDatabase(@RequestBody FirstRequestorBean bean) {

        logger.info(bean.getId());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and bean class

```
public class FirstRequestorBean {


    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



}
```

the xml passed here is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FirstRequestorBean>
    <name>Akhil</name>
    <id>1</id>
</FirstRequestorBean>
```

getting a Unsupported Media Type exception.

can someone point out how to resolve the issue

Comment: Try removing your XML file header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and try adding `MediaType.TEXT_XML`.

Comment: produces = {MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE},consumes={MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE}) tried adding this @CrazySabbath .still the same error

Comment: Either you misspelled your comment, or you didn't understand me. Have you tried adding `TEXT_XML` (notice, not `TEXT_XML_VALUE`) and removing xml header?

Comment: @CrazySabbath yes. I tried removing xml header and using the Mediatype.TEXT_XML .still fetched me the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Post request will have a "content-type" which needs to match up to the "consumes" parameter for your request mapping.

For XML there are two types "application/xml" and "text/xml" it is good practice to accept both, (`MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE` & `MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE`).

Additionally you have:
`produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}` this is your return type, you only need to define this once you are actually returning something, seeing as are only setting a status code then this should be removed.

Comment: I have tried both the specific steps but still getting an error

Comment: What is the content type for your request?

Comment: Hi MartinByers, I was able to resolve the issue ,supposedly was using a tool Jmeter for which I had not set the appropriate Accept Headers , after which it worked.More of a tool settings issue then it was of code.Thank you for the support

Comment: @MartinByers - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59485326/spring-boot-rest-how-to-read-xml-nested-request-at-controller?

Answer (score -1):

1. Add **MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE** to accept XML form of data on your request mapping. 
   Ex:- (Here application accepts both JSON and XML format as request)
   @PostMapping(value = "/users/add", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
2. Add **@XmlRootElement** annotation to your bean class
3. Add appropriate **Content-Type (application/json or application/xml)** in the header of your request